# When a map (used as a function) is given two arguments

Tags: clojure

I was browsing the source of Ring:

```
(def redirect-status-codes
  {:moved-permanently 301
   :found 302
   :see-other 303
   :temporary-redirect 307
   :permanent-redirect 308})

(defn redirect
  ([url] (redirect url :found))
  ([url status]
   {:status  (redirect-status-codes status status)
    :headers {"Location" url}
    :body    ""}))
```

Why `(redirect-status-codes status status)` instead of `(redirect-status-codes status)`? And why (how) does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redirect` is coded this way on purpose so it can accept either a keyword or a number as `status`.

As to how does `(redirect-status-codes status status)` work, check out [the Clojure reference on maps](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Maps).

> Maps implement IFn, for invoke() of one argument (a key) with an optional **second argument (a default value)**

So for `(redirect "https://www.google.com")`, the map invocation becomes `(redirect-status-codes :found :found)`. Since `:found` is a key of `redirect-status-codes`, it returns the respective value, `302`; the second `:found` has no effect on the return.

For `(redirect "https://www.google.com" 302)`, the map invocation becomes `(redirect-status-codes 302 302)`. This time `302` is not a key of `redirect-status-codes`, so the second argument, `302`, is returned as the default value.

Answer (score 2):

The last argument is the default -- the value to be return if no match is found.

Thus, we're looking up `status` in `redirect-status-codes`, but using its existing value should it not be present in that map (which would happen if, for example, the value were *already* numeric).